# Use of regular expressions and iteration index in Java 8 streams

Tags: regex, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to extract transactions from my bank statement and put them in a database.

As step one, i have my statement in a statement.txt file and it contains the following sample data.

```
...some lines of text

11/29/16 Online scheduled transfer to SAV 8075 Confirmation# 1098489998 -500.00
11/29/16 KEEP THE CHANGE TRANSFER TO ACCT 8075 FOR 11/29/16 -0.09
11/30/16 CHECKCARD 1129 TONNELLE MART PROFESSIO NORTH BERGEN NJ
24055236335400648000752
-17.76
11/30/16 CHECKCARD 1129 STATE FARM 800-956-6310 IL 24610436334004074264281 RECURRING -297.09

...some more transactions and text.
```

As you can see, some of the data is flowing into the next line.
I am reading the lines into a stream as below.

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("statement.txt"),Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Now, how can I achieve the following, with or without Streams?

1. Any line that starts with an mm/dd/yy format and ends with an amount format should be added to another text file or arrayList called 'transactions'
2. When a line breaks into multiple (lets say one transaction breaks up into max 3 lines and we know it) the lines should be concatenated and returned.

Here are my regexes for date and amount:

```
String date= "^[0-3]?[0-9]/[0-3]?[0-9]/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}\\s.";
String amount = "^-?\\d+(\\.\\[0-9][0-9]).";
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Try `Java.util.Scanner` which can read text from a file, matching a regex across line breaks. Java 9 has new APIs that produce a stream of matches from a `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it ther below way.. its not perfect.. help me improve

put this method in any class with psvm

```
static ArrayList<String> printMatchers(){
        String fileName = "/Users/dhananjayraparla/Desktop/GitHub/Groovy/BankStatementViewer/src/main/resources/Statements.txt";
        Pattern date = Pattern.compile("^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]");
        Pattern amount = Pattern.compile("-?\\d{0,3},?\\d{0,3}\\.\\d{2}$");
        //read file into stream, try-with-resources
        String previous=new String();
        List<String> lines = null;
        try {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {

            Matcher dt = date.matcher(lines.get(i));
            Matcher amt = amount.matcher(lines.get(i));

            if ( dt.find() && amt.find() ){
                    System.out.println( lines.get(i) );
                    filteredList.add( lines.get(i) );
            } 
            else if (i<lines.size()-2) {
                String temp1 = lines.get(i)+" "+lines.get(i+1);
                Matcher dt2 = date.matcher(temp1);
                Matcher amt2 = amount.matcher(temp1);

                String temp2 = lines.get(i)+" "+lines.get(i+1)+" "+lines.get(i+2);
                Matcher dt3 = date.matcher(temp2);
                Matcher amt3 = amount.matcher(temp2);
                if (dt2.find() && amt2.find()) {
                    System.out.println(temp1);
                    filteredList.add(temp1);
                } else if (dt3.find() && amt3.find()) {
                    System.out.println(temp2);
                    filteredList.add(temp2);
                } 
            }
        }
        try {
            Path out = Paths.get("/Users/dhananjayraparla/Desktop/GitHub/Groovy/BankStatementViewer/src/main/resources/filteredTransactionList.txt");
            Files.write(out,filteredList,Charset.defaultCharset());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filteredList;

    }
```

As you can see.. i wrote my own patterns

```
Pattern date = Pattern.compile("^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]");
Pattern amount = Pattern.compile("-?\\d{0,3},?\\d{0,3}\\.\\d{2}$");
```

And did not use Java 8 streams.

This is my input

```
11/17/16 GAS MART AT BR  11/17 #000157975 PURCHASE GAS MART AT BRO     -1.75
continued on the next page
   !   = 1725 0868   !   October 20, 2016 to November 17, 2016
Page 6 of 6
Withdrawals and other subtractions - continued
Date Description Amount
11/17/16 PLANET FIT       DES:CLUB FEES  ID:1632102280753  INDN:       CO
ID:1710602737 PPD  PMT INFO:516-861-2109
-10.00
11/17/16 KEEP THE CHANGE TRANSFER TO  FOR 11/17/16 -0.99
Total withdrawals and other subtractions -$4,186.00
Service fees
Date Transaction description Amount
10/20/16 P199657         10/19 #000008705 WITHDRWL 199    FEE
-2.50
```

and this is my output

```
11/17/16 GAS MART AT BR  11/17 #000157975 PURCHASE GAS MART AT BRO        NY -1.75
11/17/16 PLANET FIT       DES:CLUB FEES  ID:1632102280753  INDN:       CO ID:1710602737 PPD  PMT INFO:516-861-2109 -10.00
11/17/16 KEEP THE CHANGE TRANSFER TO  FOR 11/17/16 -0.99
10/20/16 P199657         10/19 #000008705 WITHDRWL 199   FEE -2.50
```

I would like to know how to use streams to get this result

Answer (score 2):

You're asking a lot of things. I propose you break them down a bit, that will help you see that what you're asking isn't too hard: File reading, parsing, concatenating, then file writing. Split it all.

I've tried using Streams, and forEach methods with predicates.

I wasn't too sure about what you meant with file writing or returning:

> 1. Any line that [...] should be added to another text file or arrayList called 'transactions
> 2. When a line breaks into multiple [...] the lines should be concatenated and returned.

I've concatenated split lines to a single line, you then can do whatever you want with the result.

Here's my (**completely untested**, but compiling) code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TestStream {
    public void main(String[] argc) throws IOException{
        Stream<String> lineStream = streamFile("testFile.txt");  // Stream Input text
        List<String> transactionList = new ArrayList<>(); // Prepare result list
        Map<Boolean, List<String>> transactionstream = lineStream.collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.matches("^[0-3]?[0-9]/[0-3]?[0-9]/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}\\s")));
        transactionstream.forEach((success, transactionContent) -> {
            if(!success)
                return;
            String concat = transactionContent.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
            transactionList.add(concat);
        });
    }

    public Stream<String> streamFile(final String filename) throws IOException {
        Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename));
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Basically I:

- Dump the file to a Stream using Files.lines()
- Partition the lines to split whenever a lines begins with a date
  --> this gives a `Map<Boolean, List<String>>` where the boolean denotes a match, and the List contains successive lines where only the first starts with a date (i.e. its a transaction)
- Using forEach on the map, I then Stream the piece-wise transactions and use a joining Collector, and finally put the concatenated string in `transactionList`.
- Job done, the result is in transactionList. I leave to you to do something useful with this transaction list.

I believe it's impossible to leverage the full potential of `Stream`s for this task, because:

- The whole file must be read before being put into a `Streams`
- Some lines are inter-dependant and thus the partitioning has to scan the whole file straight away

So the Streams will not be able to be lazy & efficient. but it's much shorter than your manual solution.

**Warning**: I haven't added any separator to concatenate the lines, this might mess up the content. You might want a separator. Luckily, you can do just that with the *other* `Collector.joining()` method!

Comment: i tried your approach in my use case and ran into some issues while trying to add lines.. i will do a detailed post later .. u can use the sample input data i posted in a txt file to test out ur program in the meanwhile.